# Is it possible to keep the old paths when nesting a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following in my routes.rb file:

```
  resources :businesses do 
    resources :branches
  end
```

This (correctly) generates the following routes:

```
    business_branches GET    /businesses/:business_id/branches(.:format)          branches#index
                      POST   /businesses/:business_id/branches(.:format)          branches#create
  new_business_branch GET    /businesses/:business_id/branches/new(.:format)      branches#new
 edit_business_branch GET    /businesses/:business_id/branches/:id/edit(.:format) branches#edit
      business_branch GET    /businesses/:business_id/branches/:id(.:format)      branches#show
                      PUT    /businesses/:business_id/branches/:id(.:format)      branches#update
                      DELETE /businesses/:business_id/branches/:id(.:format)      branches#destroy
```

The problem is this: I'd like to enjoy the URL path nesting **without having to change all my links** to use the new path names.

I tried the following, to no avail:

```
  resources :businesses do 
    resources :branches, as 'branches'
  end
```

Comment: What does the old paths look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible without changing your paths a little bit. For example you have to include the business_id.

So if you have:

```
resources :businesses do 
  resources :branches
end
```

the edit path for example should look like this:

```
edit_business_branch_path(business_id: 123, id: 456)
```

What you can do is to add a scope in your routes:

```
scope ":business_id" do
  resources :branches
end
```

Generated routes:

```
    branches GET    /:business_id/branches(.:format)           branches#index
             POST   /:business_id/branches(.:format)           branches#create
  new_branch GET    /:business_id/branches/new(.:format)       branches#new
 edit_branch GET    /:business_id/branches/:id/edit(.:format)  branches#edit
      branch GET    /:business_id/branches/:id(.:format)       branches#show
             PATCH  /:business_id/branches/:id(.:format)       branches#update
             PUT    /:business_id/branches/:id(.:format)       branches#update
             DELETE /:business_id/branches/:id(.:format)       branches#destroy
```

Now the path is like you want, **but** you still have to include the business_id:

```
edit_branch_path(business_id: 123, id: 456)
```

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't seem to be working. All of my old paths were the standard paths expected from running resources :branches without nesting it under businesses

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain some of the contents. If you do explain this (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame this can't work without adding the business_id!